WINAPI Esc key handling in Dialog
There had been written multiple posts on internet about the people annoyed by default ESC key handling in dialog boxes, but this is what I actually expect but cannot have.
In shorts my dialog definition in resources
ID_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 200, 200
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
PUSHBUTTON "Cancel", ID_CUSTOM_CANCEL, 10, 10, 50, 14
END

I show this dialog by:
DialogBox(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_DIALOG), hwnd_main, DialogCallback);

When I click the button, dialog callback function is called with Message == WM_COMMAND and lParam==ID_CUSTOM_CANCEL.
When I click "close" button on dialog caption, dialog callback function is called with Message == WM_COMMAND and lParam==ID_CANCEL.
But when I press ESC key, dialog callback function is never called.
I know there are few methods to handle that in my code, but I expect Windows should have a kind native support as have ENTER key support for default pushbutton.
I know I could handle same by WM_KEYDOWN or define accelerator keys, but is there any less "manual" way to handle that?
While testing different dialog behaviours I noticed if I add TEXT control and enter this control then ESC works like magic. I initially assumed the problem was with TABSTOP settings, as even in example above I did not add WS_TABSTOP to PUSHBUTTON, but then I found the TABSTOP does not work, until I manually select one control on the dialog.
Following this path I found the solution of my problem. Somebody else had same problem with TABSTOP, and the root cause was missingreturn TRUE at the end of WM_INITDIALOG.
Worked as charm for me, both ESC key and TABSTOP works now.
It looks like dialog nomatter if it is on the top of everything on the screen, it has not have a kind of focus if WM_INITDIALOG has not been processed correctly.

"I expect Windows should have a kind native support" - It does. So long as your dialog template has a button with ID IDCANCEL. Yours doesn't, so there's not much native support to be expected.

In LOWORD(wparam) of WM_COMMAND, just use EndDialog in IDCANCEL.

@IInspectable
I had alredy tried without success #define ID_CUSTOM_CANCEL IDCANCEL
Just to be fully convinced I made update PUSHBUTTON definition, from ID_CUSTOM_CANCEL to IDCANCEL and rebuild, still not working.
I had verified final exe file with reshacker, this button has id 2 (=IDCANCEL)

@Torrecto-MSFT I put debuger breakpoint on whatever comes on WM_COMMAND, and when I press ESC nothing happen.

@odo Attention! You should use wParam not lParam! Please refer to Use of the wParam and lParam parameters are summarized here.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command. If esc still does not function, please show your message code, at least a minimal reproducible sample.

@odo Does it work after changing to loword wparam? I'm waiting for your feedback.

It is not mandatory for WM_INITDIALOG to return TRUE. You can return FALSE just fine. What is required is that the dialog procedure sets the input focus to a non-disabled control. If you don't you have essentially disabled the keyboard interface entirely. If you provide a [mcve] I can write up an answer that explains this in detail.

@Torrecto-MSFT I might mixed the value of lparam and wparam hi/lo part in initial question. But this is only secondary issue. Primary issue was a lack of WM_COMMAND message related to ESC key at all.

@IInspectable My observations are completely the opposite, returning TRUE for WM_INITDIALOG makes a difference. As I understand windows message API, returning TRUE, means the message will not be removed from the message queue, and some higher level process/queue may also react to this as well. In my case returning TRUE makes dialog window looks more alive, it started responding to TAB and ESC. I could guess, the same goal could be achieved with SetFocus to dialog window or dialog control, but why to do this manually when OS GUI should do this automatic?

I would like to thank everyone for effort you put into investigation, but I will not prepare reproduction example. For me the case is closed.

None of that is true. If you provide a [mcve] I can write up an answer so that you and future visitors don't have to guess (and get it wrong).

How I discovered solution is described in the last paragraph of question.
The root cause was the lack of return TRUE after processing WM_INITDIALOG.
More details are in the MSDN current link to the message documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-initdialog

The control to receive the default keyboard focus is always the first control in the dialog box that is visible, not disabled, and that has the WS_TABSTOP style. When the dialog box procedure returns TRUE, the system checks the control to ensure that the procedure has not disabled it. If it has been disabled, the system sets the keyboard focus to the next control that is visible, not disabled, and has the WS_TABSTOP.
An application can return FALSE only if it has set the keyboard focus to one of the controls of the dialog box.

Mentioned also on Giving dialogbox focus

"The root cause was the lack of return TRUE after processing WM_INITDIALOG" - That's not the root cause. It is a side-effect of returning TRUE from the WM_INITDIALOG message handler that "magically" makes things appear to work. If you want to learn what that "magic" is update the question with your faulting dialog procedure. If you don't this Q&A is useless to future visitors. You might want to take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works.

You also should summarize Use of the wParam and lParam parameters up. Then you can mark your answer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
